# Clicking inside canvas element selects text

Tags: javascript, html

I have a canvas element in my HTML document. When I click inside of the canvas multiple times, it selects part of my `<h1>` element's text, which is before the `<canvas>` tag. Is there a way to stop this from happening? I am guessing there is a JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Returning `false` in an event stops the standard event from happening:

```
document.getElementById('canvas').onmousedown = function(){
  return false;
};
```

Edit: I just found out that text selection is done before `onclick` is fired, a better option is `onmousedown`.

Comment: Here's how you do it in jQuery: `$("#canvas").on("mousedown", function () { return false; });`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `mousedown` event to do other things, you can prevent only text selection more specifically by setting the `onselectstart` event to return `false`.

```
//give your canvas an id, I used 'can'    
var canvas = document.getElementById('can');
canvas.onselectstart = function () { return false; }
```